# How to print out a yaml::Node?

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I have tried many different ways to do this. I have a bunch of nodes nested under each other e.g:

```
yaml::Node a;
a["foo"] = 3;
yaml::Node b;
b["baz"] = 7;
a["bar"] = b;
```

I just want to print a to a string so I can see what the yaml looks like. I've tried the following:

```
a.as<std::string>()
```

as well as

```
std:: string str;
a >> str;
```

The first throws an exception while the second doesn't compile.

What am I missing? This feels like it should be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can print Node using `Emitter`

```cpp
Emitter emitter;
emitter << node;
std::cout<<"Node :" <<emitter.c_str()<<std::endl;
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The node is populated correctly, but all I get is the string "true". I'm using yaml-cpp 0.6.2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: In response to my own comment, you need to include the following for it to work:
`#include <yaml-cpp/node/emit.h>` in addition to: `#include <yaml-cpp/node/parse.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/node/impl.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/emitter.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Dump function. i.e.

```
yaml::Node a;
a["foo"] = 3;
yaml::Node b;
b["baz"] = 7;
a["bar"] = b;

std::string yaml_string = YAML::Dump(a);
```